# Jenkins pipeline mocking with Groovy

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, groovy, closures, jenkins-pipeline

I'm quite new to the Jenkins pipeline stuff and I am building a small shared library in Groovy.
In this context I am trying to come up with some unit tests, and then I have to mock the pipeline object.

Basically I am having a Groovy class containing a method that does some stuff with credentials:

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {

  def pipeline

  MyClass(def pipeline) {
    this.pipeline = pipeline
  }

  void my method(String version) {
    pipeline.withCredentials([pipeline.usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'MY_ID', usernameVariable: 'MY_USER', passwordVariable: 'MY_PASSWORD')]) {
        pipeline.sh "./release.sh complete --username ${MY_USER} --password ${MY_PASSWORD} --version '${version}'"
    }
  }
}
```

So when it comes to unit testing this method I have created a PipelineMock Groovy class to (try to) mock the `withCredentials` and `usernamePassword`.

The test class is like this (a bit simplified):

```
class MyClassTest {

  @Test
  void callWithWithVersionShouldCallCommad() {
    def pipelineMock = new PipelineMock()
    def myClass = new MyClass(pipelineMock)
    myClass('1.0.1')
    assertTrue(pipelineMock.commandCalled.startsWith('./release.sh complete'))
  }

}
```

And the PipelineMock I came up with is:

```
class PipelineMock {

  String commandCalled

  def sh(String command) {
    commandCalled = command
  }

  def usernamePassword(Map inputs) {
    inputs
  }

  def withCredentials(List args, Closure closure) {
    for (arg in args) {
        closure.setProperty(arg.get('usernameVariable'), 'the_login')
        closure.setProperty(arg.get('passwordVariable'), 'the_password')
    }
    closure()
  }

}
```

Initially I was just calling the `closure()` so to execute the code, but I got the error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MY_USER for class: MyClass` when the execution reaches the `pipeline.sh` line.
So I tried to inject test values into `MY_USER` and `MY_PASSWORD` so they can be resolved with the `for` loop. I got the exact same error but this time when calling the `closure.setProperty`. I checked at debug time and the `arg.get('usernameVariable')` resolves correctly to `MY_USER`.

So well, I'm lost. I'm not really a Groovy expert, so I probably miss something. Any help on understanding what's happening would be appreciated!

Comment: Jenkins does some low level compiler and runtime changes to Groovy, and it is very difficult to mock those.. I would recommend looking at [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) and possibly [this Gradle plugin](https://github.com/mkobit/jenkins-pipeline-shared-libraries-gradle-plugin) (note: I'm the author of the plugin) to see if those help you.

Comment: @mkobit Yes, JenkinsPipelineUnit should be the right right answer, but the reason for the OP's code not working is not because of Jenkins runtime. I believe the OP was trying to run it as a regular Groovy unit test with no Jenkins runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does look like an ideal candidate for using [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) as @mkobit mentioned in a comment, but for the sake of academic interest, the sample in the question would in fact work with minor changes related to delegator. There is also a typo in the original `MyClass.my method` which I believe should have been `MyClass.call`. Here is the working `PipelineMock`

```
class PipelineMock {

  String commandCalled

  def sh(String command) {
    commandCalled = command
  }

  def usernamePassword(Map inputs) {
    inputs
  }

  def withCredentials(List args, Closure closure) {
    def delegate = [:]
    for (arg in args) {
        delegate[arg.get('usernameVariable')] = 'the_login'
        delegate[arg.get('passwordVariable')] = 'the_password'
    }
    closure.delegate = delegate
    closure()
  }

}
```

And here is the `MyClass` without the typo:

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {

  def pipeline

  MyClass(def pipeline) {
    this.pipeline = pipeline
  }

  void call(String version) {
    pipeline.withCredentials([pipeline.usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'MY_ID', usernameVariable: 'MY_USER', passwordVariable: 'MY_PASSWORD')]) {
        pipeline.sh "echo ./release.sh complete --username ${MY_USER} --password ${MY_PASSWORD} --version '${version}'"
    }
  }
}
```

The test should work as is.

Comment: Thanks @haridsv for the explanation and adjustment on my initial code! I will dig into this `delegate` thing.